# Copy & Copy does not work correctly with stringlist

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-xe3, tstringlist

i got a big xml file and i want to save each id, source & target in a stringlist to generate after successfull import to stringlists build a query to mysql.

heres a snippet of my xml:

```
xliff version="1.1">
 <file original="Xliff Demo" source-language="EN" target-language="DE" datatype="html">
 <header>
 <skl>
 <external-file uid="017dbcf0-c82c-11e2-ba2b-005056c00008" href="skl\simple.htm.skl"/>
 </skl>
 </header>
 <body>
 <trans-unit id="00ffmnpB5wBV5KFqBxuHLi4fwJvvuB">
 <source xml:lang="EN">1lnRUfBBeHtbS96uULSht42VNMN7XE4qt9JrOcWhtoTuhnbAQ9</source>
 <target xml:lang="DE">zZvOLJfLCy9oP5GQYfEqw5LAeC2ESAxRmVe1JyQdmJ1eG2jz1N</target>
 <note/></trans-unit>
 <trans-unit id="00kjUwy1rJ54bEGYp7XZvtBiY32pmj">
 <source xml:lang="EN">HXOQLUWkfJg206vRw8lyWhCWChOacVxbMukfQ0HUdNHSI18GG4</source>
 <target xml:lang="DE">8dsX38mezeZ0w0w37LI66CDRuI8gBD23zT5KR4iqYNv3IGUgH0</target>
 <note/></trans-unit>
 <trans-unit id="00kk3Af8SFpHyelAaYrgK58b9GbIDj">
 <source xml:lang="EN">wQFxZiCiRsSNWs20G4WXAmDBRdRL6fcrrJnCgtbiXGSfHzpYrT</source>
 <target xml:lang="DE">oFVTUdPkExOhISYofIImLsnVKd3NSZg32tyeP5iRxRZdmuYQDy</target>
 <note/></trans-unit>
 <trans-unit id="00Ky2dmDU9wGTWBnJxeL9b9gkts5UQ">
 <source xml:lang="EN">nHQcjAW02lWe0SyOhqGtyqUhpwQ8qgWX3rUynMRf4BDHfVdHOC</source>
 <target xml:lang="DE">0CURp1dcZydB1V2rEZ1lnOhmYufOYbrLbh84e1ZnALlzZPVq4F</target>
 <note/></trans-unit>
 <trans-unit id="00pMSFlBfA3bJ8Xy9I78wz6XisPYcV">
 <source xml:lang="EN">IuhtaVnZtF67nxKz5dbmuy8BEMTs2X1120FzDtIplKF2Me5AsQ</source>
 <target xml:lang="DE">1BGSJQDZBm4UW974pucnX3XHuYOQYpC7nTcIH01rbKlOkVi9bo</target>
 <note/></trans-unit>
 <trans-unit id="012w2kb2d1Lo6NbJLE0BawThzsSuCJ">
 <source xml:lang="EN">0RoniOGZ7V7WTF1YQg59B8jBhRxnLVXscC1LOGPzKPYRs76oIz</source>
 <target xml:lang="DE">gyw15fkHTni2aUGWI5qiPHEz8vsJJJsW4OOqKwGYL1qzfUVfLO</target>
 <note/></trans-unit>
...
..
..
```

So i try to save each entry of trans-unit id, source xml:lang"EN", target xml:lang="DE" in a seperate stringlist but only the values.

Thats my code:

```
{ -----------  Import Procedure ------------ }
procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  xmlFile, idList, sourceList, targetList: TStringList; // StringListe wo die Xml Datei eingelesen wird
  i: Integer;
  id, source, target: String;
  idTmp, idTmp2, sourceTmp, sourceTmp2, targetTmp, targetTmp2: Integer;
begin
  try
    xmlFile := TStringList.Create;
    idList := TStringList.Create;
    sourceList := TStringList.Create;
    targetList := TStringList.Create;

    if OpenDialog1.Execute then
      xmlFile.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);

      {Debug}
        //ShowMessage(IntToStr(XmlFile.Count));   Ausgabe der Zeilenlänge
        //ShowMessage(XmlFile[8]);                // Ausgabe der Zeile 8
      {/Debug}

      for i := 0 to xmlFile.Count-1 do // Über alle Zeilen der StringList gehen und folgendes tun:
        begin // Code pro Zeile

          {id}
          idTmp  := Pos('<trans-unit id="', xmlFile.Strings[i])+16;  //  Sucht nach trans-unit id   (16 ist die Anzahl der Länge vom Suchstring in dem Fall trans-unit id 16 Stellen lang
          if idTmp > 5 then // Überprüfen ob was gefunden wurde (Ungleich 0)
          begin
            idTmp2 := Pos('"', xmlFile.Strings[i], idTmp); // Ermittelt die Position vom Ende des Strings (")
            idList.Add(Copy(xmlFile.Strings[i], idTmp, idTmp2-idTmp));
          end;

          {source}
          sourceTmp  := Pos('<source xml:lang="EN">', xmlFile.Strings[i])+22;
          if sourceTmp > 5 then // Überprüfen ob was gefunden wurde (Ungleich 0)
          begin
            sourceTmp2 := Pos('<', xmlFile.Strings[i], sourceTmp); // Ermittelt die Position vom Ende des Strings (")
            sourceList.Add(Copy(xmlFile.Strings[i], sourceTmp, sourceTmp2-sourceTmp));
          end;

          {target}
          targetTmp  := Pos('<target xml:lang="DE">', xmlFile.Strings[i])+22;
          if targetTmp > 5 then // Überprüfen ob was gefunden wurde (Ungleich 0)
          begin
            targetTmp2 := Pos('<', xmlFile.Strings[i], targetTmp); // Ermittelt die Position vom Ende des Strings (")
            targetList.Add(Copy(xmlFile.Strings[i], targetTmp, targetTmp2-targetTmp));
          end;
        end;

      StartPerformance;
      UniConnection1.Open;
  finally
    ListBox1.items.assign(idList);
    ListBox2.items.assign(sourceList);
    ListBox3.items.assign(targetList);
    ShowMessage('Import in StringListen fertiggestellt.');
    xmlFile.Free;
    idList.Free;
    sourceList.Free;;
    targetList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

But it's not working like i want. My problem is, that it saves empty lines too in the stringlist and other trash. I dont really find my error and its the first time im using this copy/pos function.

Heres a screenshot

[image]

What should i change to fixx my problem and only save the correct strings in my 3 stringlists?

Comment: already the first `if idTmp > 5` and similar will allways be true

Comment: No, that's not how to parse XML.

Comment: Never ever try to parse XML yourself. See here why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers - I think that's more specifically a jab at trying to do the job with regex... while perhaps somewhat less nebulously perilous than using regex, I agree that OP's solution remains a shiver-inducing ad-hoc approach that is sanely best avoided.

Comment: I read that parsing answer much broader: if even a powerful ad-hoc approach cannot parse HTML or XML, what ad-hoc approach can? Answer for XML: none. You need an XML parser (like a DOM) to do it properly.

Comment: @J... The approach in the code is no better than regex. Looking at the code, I cannot see a tokenizer, for a start. The sentiment of bobince's seminal answer applies equally here.

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers - I agree, of course.  I suppose the best analogy is that of toying with petrol vs playing with semtex.  While both ill advised, the lesser of the two ad-hoc approaches is generally, by its own unwieldiness, at least more self-limiting in the degree of monster it can become before its author realizes the futility of the approach.  I fully admit, however, that I may be woefully underestimating the resolve with which a determined madman might grow the above into a million line fiend of a program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here :

```
idTmp  := Pos('<trans-unit id="', xmlFile.Strings[i])+16;  
if idTmp > 5 then 
  ...
```

`idTmp` will always be greater than 5 - you are adding 16 to it no matter what and it always returns a positive value (or zero if no match).

The simplest change here would be :

```
 idTmp  := Pos('<trans-unit id="', xmlFile.Strings[i]);  
 if idTmp > 0 then begin //Pos returns 0 if no match found
   idTmp := idTmp + 16;
   idTmp2 := PosEx('"', xmlFile.Strings[i], idTmp); 
   idList.Add(Copy(xmlFile.Strings[i], idTmp, idTmp2-idTmp));
 end;
```

The change for the other two blocks would follow in a similar way.

You'll notice that I used StrUtils.PosEx here for `idTmp2` - I don't know how your code compiled using Pos for the second function...

**Edit**

Ok, it looks like Pos was changed in XE3 to include offset overloads.  If performance is your objective here (as it seems from comments) you should probably have a read of this :

http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=111103

Additionally, which I think is probably quite important, this really is a terrible way to parse XML.  I highly suggest you read through some source code from projects that do this already to get a better understanding of how you should approach the problem.  Some examples might be :

- [omniXml](http://code.google.com/p/omnixml/source/checkout)
- [NativeXml](http://www.simdesign.nl/xml.html)

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you should think about using the [IXMLDocument](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/XMLIntf.IXMLDocument) interface to load the XML File into a data structure and fill your stringlists afterwards.

An example has been posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8651934/2207071

Comment: I still know of the existence of this component. But i should use a own function to read these & import.

Comment: @Polymorphin - Any reason why?

Comment: I wanna diff the import speed with the componenet and without and own function.

Comment: @Polymorphin - this may be of interest, then : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9495243/327083

Comment: I think the line idTmp2 := Pos('"', xmlFile.Strings[i], idTmp); and similar ones are incorrect. The offset should be (idTmp + 1) or otherwise you will find the first '"' again.

Comment: @Polymorphin - yes, the zip is offline but there is a good collection of performance data (and a number of good libraries to try) if you are interested in comparing the speed of XML libraries.  Unless you really need maximum performance from a custom algorithm, generally I would think that using a good library is always a better alternative.  It will generally be a more stable and robust solution than something custom made.